# Error 500 when accessing deployed Symfony2 project

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, deployment

I was developing **Symfony2** website on my local machine and after i finished, i uploaded it to our company's remote test server via FTP.

When I try to access it by typing either:

- `www.project_name.company_website.cz/`
- `www.project_name.company_website.cz/web/`
- `www.project_name.company_website.cz/web/app.php`

I get **error 500**.

This app runs well on my local machine but I don't know what is wrong on remote server. My thought is that there is no index file in project's root or `.htaccess` but I am new to web development so I don't have enough information about this.

Comment: check error log of your web server (apache) and/or symfony logs (``app/logs/*``)

Comment: You are having this error because on of this reason 

 - Permission issue : check if apache have the write permission in your cache directory samething with logs directory
 - Database connection issue : check if you are using the write configuration in the parameters.yml.dist file

Comment: There is nothing related in symfony logs, now I am trying to get access to server logs.

Comment: When deploying don't copy the contents of your cache directory.

Comment: I tried to copy it without cache and it didn't help.